# Make changes on date's list as per needed

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have created a list of dates of current week like this:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dates = [(now + datetime.timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%B %d") for d in range(7)]
print (dates)
```

Which is returning me list like that:

```
['February 08', 'February 09', 'February 10', 'February 11', 'February 12', 'February 13', 'February 14']
```

Now what I want is, dates before 10 should be displaying with one digit only, like this:

```
['February 8', 'February 9', 'February 10', 'February 11', 'February 12', 'February 13', 'February 14']
```

Comment: The platform-specific `%-d` gives non-zeropadded day number - but it's platform specific. So won't work on Windows for example.

Answer (score 0):

After working my *** off, I finally come to conclusion, that instead of working with dates, I can work string slicing, so I have implemented following logic:

```
final_dates = [sub.replace(' 0', ' ') for sub in dates]
print(final_dates)
```